# Label a checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i'm not familiar with jquery.

What i'm trying to do is, drag and drop a text which will be displayed as a checkbox and the checkbox should have the id and tooltip same to the dropped-text. For that i used the following code.but it's not working.please help

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(init);

  function init() {




  function addColumn(column) 
  {
    var iHtml;


    //Labeling and Tool Tip the Checkbox



   iHtml = "<span title='ToolTipText'>"+
   "<input id='<%" + column + ".ClientID%>' type='checkbox' name='<%" + column + ".ClientID %>' />"+
    "<label for='<%" + column + ".ClientID%>'>MyCheckBox</label></span>";

    return iHtml
  }
```

Comment: *"...is label an i used thed put tooltip to a checkbox..."* Before clicking Post Your Question, it's well worth reading your question over and dealing with at least the worst of the typos. I genuinely don't know what that sentence is meant to say. I could guess, but...

Comment: Yes, please clarify your question, im not sure what you mean :)

Comment: some network issues and typing mistakes resulted in that and please forgive me and read the updated question

Comment: The code is taken out of its context. We need the rest of it to see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of problems with that code. For one thing, although [HTML5 allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) just about any character in an `id` other than a space, earlier versions of HTML [were more restrictive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [CSS still is](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), so you really don't want to start an `id` with a `#`. (You can avoid using an `id` entirely in this case, unless you need the `id` for code you haven't quoted.) Your `input` type has a typo ("checbox") and so it won't be a checkbox, it'll default to "text".

Here's my best guess at what you want:

```
iHtml = "<label title='ToolTipText'>" +
        "<input id='x<%” + column + ".ClientID%>' type='checkbox' name='x<%” +column+".ClientID%>'/>" +
        " MyCheckBox</label>";
```

...but I'm not at all sure your ASP.Net aspects in there are right (I've left it as you had it), looks dodgy to me but I don't do a lot of ASP.Net. (Not least the fancy `”` character.)

What I did above:

- Make the `id` and `name` start with an `x` and got rid of the `#`. See the links above for why. (I left the `id` because I wasn't sure you didn't need it; if you don't need it, if the `name` is enough, you can remove it.)
- Put the `input` *inside* the `label`. When you do that, you can avoid the whole `for` thing.
- Put the `title` on the `label`, no need for an extra `span`.
- Corrected the `type`.
- Put the text of all attributes in single quotes. This is largely stylistic, at least in HTML (quoting attriutes is not stylistic in XHTML, it's required).

Comment: i need the id of the same in code behind. The checkbox should have a label as well as a tooltiptext i converted an asp control to html to get that details and thats why i used span and all. What i'm getting is an error saying ';' expected.

Comment: @NewBie: I think that probably relates to the fancy quote mark just after the `<%`. Or...this *is* on an ASP.Net page, right? those `<%` and `%>` are going to get processed server-side, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blablabla" value="myvalue" class="myclass"/> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#blabla").attr({title: "mytooltip"})
            .before(function(){
                      return "<label for=" + this.id +">MyLabelText</label>"
            });
});
</script>
```

or short form

```
$(
$("#blabla").attr({title:"mytooltip"})
            .before("<label for='blabla'>MyLabelText</label>");
);
```

Comment: Checkbox is generated with a script. These i dont understand